# locale shows different settings for root user

Tags: 20.04, bash, locale

I'm confused about the locale settings on my system.
I have an Ubuntu 20.04.3 server that I connect to via Putty.

I'm root on the system (I know. Stupid idea. But I'm just setting this up and then I don't do it anymore when I'm done.). When I run the `locale` and `sudo locale` commands on the system I get different results and I have no idea where this is coming from.

Result with `locale`:

```
# Results in
LANG=
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"
LC_TIME="POSIX"
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"
LC_PAPER="POSIX"
LC_NAME="POSIX"
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"
LC_ALL=
```

Result with `sudo locale`:

```
# Results in
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="de_DE.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

I have tried to reconfigure this with `sudo sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` but it didn't work.

The `/etc/default/locale` file looks as follows:

```
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
```

If I log in as another user all is fine.

Can anyone give me a hint as to what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the output of `locale -a | grep en_US`

Comment: The output of ```locale -a | grep en_US``` is ```en_US.utf8```
and for ```locale -a | grep de_DE``` is ```de_DE.utf8``` because i want to setup for german.

Comment: When you use `sudo`, it is likely enforcing the locale via PAM (`/etc/pam.d/sudo`). When you log in via SSH, it *should* do something similar (via `/etc/pam.d/session` ?) and *may* permit `LC_*` variables to be overwritten by the client - I don't know why that would be different for root versus non-root SSH though, unless your SSH config is applying different setups (perhaps via a `match` block)

Comment: Each account is able to override the locale settings. Changing the system default will not change anything for an account which overrides the system default anyway. Perhaps [edit] to show whather, and if so how, these accounts do that from their shell startup scipts, GUI settings, and/or etc.